# Which controller for the PR2 base

Tags: microcontroller, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I'm trying to customize the base controller on pr2. However when I compile BaseController2, the compiler tells me that a lot of functions in there are deprecated.
Which controller am I supposed to use ?

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11149/which-controller-for-the-pr2-base/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 uses the 'BaseController2' by default, so you should be able to compile, run or modify it. That said, it is possible that the controller is still using deprecated functions that result in compiler warnings.  You can file a ticket for this on the [pr2_mechanism_controllers](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism_controllers) bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-09-12**:
Ok, I will fill a ticket and in the meantime just do as if there were no warnings. Thanks.